# How to print specific value in array in python?

Tags: python-2.7

Python version 2.7.12

If I put three values in an array, how do I print only one of the values?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say you have an array/list

```
kaka = ['bobo', 'fofo', 'lolo']
```

then `print kaka[1]` gives you `fofo`

Comment: Thanks! I am new to programming and I try python. This is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
print values[0]
print values[1]
print values[2]
```