# List indices must be integers or slices, not str why the error

Tags: python

I was trying to integrate LoqateAPI for phone number validator, i want to validate bulk phones number in txt files

**BELLOW IS MY CODE**

Is anyone here to help me out please, i didn't suppose to get this type of error

```
phone_number = (
    open(
        input(f"\n{bwh}{ble}Enter Phone Number List{res}{gr} [phone.txt]{res} : "), "r"
    )
    .read()
    .splitlines()
)
access_key = input(
    f"\n{bwh}{ble}Enter Your LoqateAPI Key {res}{gr} [AA11-AA11-AA11-AA11]{res} : "
)
country_code = input(f"\n{bwh}{ble}Enter Country Code {res}{gr} [US]{res} : ")
print("------------------------------------------------------------------")
for i in phone_number:
    url = (
        "https://api.addressy.com/PhoneNumberValidation/Interactive/Validate/v2.20/json.ws?&Key="
        + access_key
        + "&Phone="
        + str(i)
        + "&Country="
        + country_code
    )
    response = requests.get(url)
    answer = response.json()
    if answer["carrier"]:

        print(url)
        print(f'{gr}{answer["number"]}{res}{yl} => {cy}{answer["carrier"]}{res}')
        save = open(f'Result/{answer["carrier"]}.txt', "a+")
        save.write(str(i) + "\n")
    else:
        print(f'{red}{answer["number"]} => Die{res}')
        dk = open("Result/die.txt", "a+")
        dk.write(str(i) + "\n")


input("Click Enter For Exit ...!")
```

This bellow text is my output
**Below is the problem I'm getting**

[image: Error image]

**

> Edited
> I print out the response from a string

**

But the respond was in a json, what type of json is this please i want to know

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQu6L.jpg)

```
    [{'PhoneNumber': '+14143392867', 'RequestProcessed': 'True', 'IsValid': 'Yes', 'NetworkCode': '180', 'NetworkName': 'AT&T Wireless', 'NetworkCountry': 'US', 'NationalFormat': '(414) 339-2867', 'CountryPrefix': '1', 'NumberType': 'Mobile'}]
[{'PhoneNumber': '+14146789198', 'RequestProcessed': 'True', 'IsValid': 'Yes', 'NetworkCode': '910', 'NetworkName': 'Google (Grand Central) - SVR', 'NetworkCountry': 'US', 'NationalFormat': '(414) 678-9198', 'CountryPrefix': '1', 'NumberType': 'VOIP'}]
[{'PhoneNumber': '+14148458738', 'RequestProcessed': 'False', 'IsValid': 'Maybe', 'NetworkCode': '', 'NetworkName': '', 'NetworkCountry': 'US', 'NationalFormat': '(414) 845-8738', 'CountryPrefix': '1', 'NumberType': 'Unknown'}]
[{'PhoneNumber': '+14141120704', 'RequestProcessed': 'True', 'IsValid': 'No', 'NetworkCode': '', 'NetworkName': '', 'NetworkCountry': 'US', 'NationalFormat': '(414) 112-0704', 'CountryPrefix': '1', 'NumberType': 'Unknown'}]
[{'PhoneNumber': '+14140646454', 'RequestProcessed': 'True', 'IsValid': 'No', 'NetworkCode': '', 'NetworkName': '', 'NetworkCountry': 'US', 'NationalFormat': '(414) 064-6454', 'CountryPrefix': '1', 'NumberType': 'Unknown'}]
Click Enter For Exit ...!
```

Comment: is it possible that `answer` has more than one value in it

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow. Quality questions have more changes of getting responses. Read [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Given enough phone numbers you'll run out of file handles. Can you think why that might be?

Comment: you have this code: `answer = response.json()` and `if answer["carrier"]:` so you are expecting `answer` to be a dictionary, but the error is telling you that you actually have a list

Comment: @Anentropic Is there a situation where response.json() might return a list?

Comment: Just want to confirm the carrier and add it to results, example (ATT Mobility.txt)

Comment: Your code fails at line 1: `Is anyone here to help me out please` is not valid python syntax

Comment: That is not the part of the code

Comment: @Vlad If the response is a JSON array rather than a JSON object, yes.

Comment: Have a look at the API docs https://www.loqate.com/resources/support/apis/PhoneNumberValidation/Interactive/Validate/2.2/ it's not very clear but they say "The response from the web service is a table" and "If an error occurs ... the response will be an error table."  We can get an error response https://api.addressy.com/PhoneNumberValidation/Interactive/Validate/v2.20/json.ws?Key=AA11-AA11-AA11-AA11&Phone=+447528471411&Country=GB&Iso3Country=True and it is a list of dictionaries. So it seems what they mean by "table" is a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary is a row in the table.

Comment: This answer is beyond my understanding, can you please enlighten me more in a flexible way so that I will quickly understand?

Answer (score 0):

**I GET IT DONE BY BYPASS OPEN BRACKET "[] IN ARRAY JSON **

Thanks everyone

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wbD4.jpg)

[Image2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090049/how-to-print-specific-value-in-array-in-python)

Someone may need help some days too
Here is the link of the threads i follow up

[How To Print Specific value in Array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090049/how-to-print-specific-value-in-array-in-python)

Comment: Your `Image2` just links to the same SO thread as the link at the bottom.  Please avoid posting information in image form.